# Sorting a list of unix time stamp values

Tags: python, sorting

Given a list of UNIX time stamp values:

```
l = ['1260633600', '1256993100', '1273255200', '1253450700']
```

I need the list to be sorted.

```
from datetime import datetime
def humanize_unixtime(unix_time):
    time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(unix_time)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H.%M')
    return time 

lsorted = sorted(l, key=lambda x: humanize_unixtime(x), reverse=True)
print [humanize_unixtime(i) for i in lsorted]
```

When I run this, I got `['31-10-2009 13.45', '20-09-2009 14.45', '12-12-2009 17.00', '07-05-2010 20.00']`, which is not at all sorted. Can you see what's wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with just basic lexical sorting? Unless your timestamps cover an unusually long time period (such that the number of digits changes) that should be correct.

Comment: I did not realize until now, the smaller the stamp the earlier. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It's numbers of seconds since the epoch, so it's monotonically increasing. The only thing to worry about is shifts in the number of digits - eg basic lexical sort will put "9" above "11". At worst if your input is the string representations of integer timestamps you could sort on `key=int` to correct for that possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the int hint. I'll fix it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sorting by the humanized output (the string), not by the times.  Notice that the first value starts with `'3'`, the second with `'2'` and the third with `'1'` which is exactly what you expect when you sort strings with `reverse=True`.

change your `key=lambda ...` to `key=int` and all should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
from datetime import datetime
l = ['1260633600', '1256993100', '1273255200', '1253450700']
def humanize_unixtime(unix_time):
    time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(unix_time)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H.%M')
    return time

lsorted = sorted(l, reverse=True)
print lsorted
print [humanize_unixtime(i) for i in lsorted]
```

here using
`lsorted = sorted(l, reverse=True)` instead of

```
lsorted = sorted(l, key=lambda x: humanize_unixtime(x), reverse=True)
```

the you will get the output as

```
['07-05-2010 23.30', '12-12-2009 21.30', '31-10-2009 18.15', '20-09-2009 18.15']
```

which is perfectly sorted

Answer (score 0):

Convert `string` type to `int` in lambda function as the unix epoch time follows incremental order.

```
from datetime import datetime
l = ['1260633600', '1256993100', '1273255200', '1253450700']
def humanize_unixtime(unix_time):
    time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(unix_time)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H.%M')
    return time

lsorted = sorted(l,key=lambda s: int(s), reverse=True)
print lsorted
print [humanize_unixtime(i) for i in lsorted]
```